# Access token gives only id, all other params are empty or null

Tags: java, ide, token, restfb

I'm new here and I tried to get started with some videos in youtube. I did all exactly like in the video, but netbeans got only my id. Graph api explorer gives me other params too, netbeans doesn't. Some arrays are empty and all other params are null.

Here are vids.

https://youtu.be/m14hYs1T3FA
https://youtu.be/GwbO_PdwK_4

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since you are new to this Platform, Please read about [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question else your question might get downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the parameter you like to receive in your call.

```
User user = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class,
        Parameter.with("fields", "id,name,email")); // this is the important part
```

Here you can see, how this is done with more explanation and deeper insights: http://restfb.com/documentation/#advanced-usage-selecting-fields

BTW these videos are highly outdated as you see on the really old RestFB version. Currently 1.49.0 is the latest version and they use something with 1.18.0! So you can take them as a hint how to start but you have to read the Facebook and the RestFB documentation.